# Unable to generate ExpatXS.dll from XML-SAX-ExpatXS-1.31 package for Windows

Tags: windows, perl

I encountered this error when running an app on Windows. After much R&D, I discovered that I needed ExpatXS.dll which is the missing component here(loadable object for module)

`Can't locate loadable object for module XML::SAX::ExpatXS in @INC (@INC contains
: C:/perl/site/lib C:/perl/lib .) at (eval 63) line 1
Compilation failed in require at (eval 63) line 1.`

So, now I have strawberry perl installed on my x86 machine and I also have the XML-SAX-ExpatXS-1.31 package 
which contains a Makefile.PL and some header file encoding.h and also ExpatXS.pm file which I guess is the perl module required to generate ExpatXS.dll(am I right ?)

Can anyone please let me know how should I compile this package to get ExpatXS.dll for windows. My main aim is to generate ExpatXS.dll for Windows.

Is this related to using cpan? I don't know much about it. So, please explain in layman's terms.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
cpan XML::SAX::ExpatXS
```

Comment: Thanks. that helped. But now I get different errors. I did `perl Makefile.PL` and after that nmake. ExpatXS.obj is created but I get linker errors `ExpatXS.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__XML_GetCurrentLineNumber referenced in function _append_error`. Although I have set the INCLUDE env variable with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Expat 2.1.0\Source\lib;` which has the declaration of XML_GetCurrentLineNumber in expat.h.

Comment: Had to set LIB env variable too. ExpatXS.dll generated :)